variables as selectors in jQuery
I'm learning jQuery and i'm essentially wondering if it's possible to use variables as selectors, like this:
let vbox = $("body").append("<div id='box'></div>");
vbox.css({
  'width': '200px',
  'height':'300px',
  'background-color':'hsl(0, 0%, 10%)',
  'border-radius':'10px',
  'position':'absolute',
  'color':'white',
'text-align':'center'
});

when I do this, the css code seems to apply to the whole document. I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with this/if it just won't work like that.
I figured out how to do it both of these ways:
var vbox = $("<div id='box'></div>")
  $("body").append(vbox)
  vbox.css({
    width:'200px',
    height:'300px',
    background:'hsl(0, 0%, 10%)',
    borderRadius:'10px',
    position:'absolute',
    color:'white',
    textAlign:'center'
  });

$("body").append("<div id='box'></div>");
  var bx = $('#box')
  bx.css({
    width:'200px',
    height:'300px',
    background:'hsl(0, 0%, 10%)',
    borderRadius:'10px',
    position:'absolute',
    color:'white',
    textAlign:'center'
  });

I'm just wondering what's different about the first way and why it doesn't work.

In your first example, you are assigning the variable to the append method on the body element - not the resulting element that's appended. So doing the vbox.css is targeting the body element. The first way works, just not the way you are expecting it to. The other two work the way you are expecting them to, because you are assigning your variable to the resulting appended element or to an element that will be created. console.log() is your friend.

You can use console.log to inspect what is in the variables vbox and bx. You will note that in the first case it's not the box...

In basic terms, chaining returns the first object.  (*)generally, some jquery methods return eg a string or specifically change the object that is returned (eg .find / .filter).  Put another way, your first line is let vbox = $("body");  box.append("...")   if you want the variable to point to the div, you could do let vbox = $("<div..>").appendTo("body") then the jquery chaining will return the newly appended div (as it's the first jquery object).


I'm just wondering what's different about the first way and why it doesn't work.

It's different because the variables reference different elements.
In this case:
let vbox = $("body").append("<div id='box'></div>");

The vbox variable is a reference to (a jQuery wrapper for) the <body> element.  So when you apply CSS styling to vbox, you apply it to the <body> element.
In these cases:
var vbox = $("<div id='box'></div>");
// and
var bx = $('#box');

These variables are references to (jQuery wrappers for) <div> elements.  So when you apply CSS to them you are applying it to those <div> elements.
Both versions "work", they're just applying CSS to different elements.

As an aside... These aren't "variables as selectors".  The selectors are the strings you pass to the $() function.  You're simply storing the results of your functions in variables, as you likely would with any function that returns a result.

That makes so much more sense, thank you!

Please accept the other answer.  This is just to provide more details on some options using your generated HTML.  Note the point of this is how to hit the DOM one time not multiple times.  I added some in-line comments.


//create the element and give it CSS, then text
//At this point it is NOT in the DOM on the page.
const vbox = $("<div></div>").css({
  width: '200px',
  height: '300px',
  background: 'hsl(0, 0%, 10%)',
  borderRadius: '10px',
  position: 'relative',
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center'
}).text('Hi');

//change the text
vbox.text('Better Howdy!');
// we can still append to the new div since all those methods return "jQuery" as they are chained
let cheese = $("<div>cheese</div>");
// we can still reference it to it since all those methods return "jQuery" as they are chained
cheese.appendTo(vbox);
//finally we hit the DOM once to append all that
vbox.appendTo('body');

// we can see we still have a reference to the element
vbox.append('<span class="beer">Beer</span>');
//we can also put something before it in the DOM
vbox.before('<span class="beer">Cold Beer</span>');
//we can also wrap it
vbox.wrap('<div class="blocky"></div>');
.beer {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #00a0ff;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.blocky {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



